# How is this game a draw?

Tags: engines, draw, lichess, chess.com

I was watching some YouTube videos, and I stumbled upon this game:

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]
[WhiteELO "?"]
[BlackELO "?"]
[SetUp "1"]
[FEN "5r2/8/pRP5/P5pP/3pk1P1/3p4/3K4/8 w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. c7 Rf2+ 2. Ke1 d2+ 3. Kxf2 d1=Q 4. Re6+ Kd3 5. c8=Q Qd2+ 6. Kg1 Qc1+ 7. Qxc1
```

After `6. Kg1 Qc1+!!   7. Qxc1` the game is draw. But how? Black still has three legal moves: `a7`, `d5`, `g6`.

Can anyone explain me how this game is a draw (I checked with chess.com and lichess.org, and several others too)?

Here's the PGN:

[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]
[WhiteELO "?"]
[BlackELO "?"]
[SetUp "1"]
[FEN "5r2/8/pRP5/P5pP/3pk1P1/3p4/3K4/8 w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. c7 Rf2+ 2. Ke1 d2+ 3. Kxf2 d1=Q 4. Re6+ Kd3 5. c8=Q Qd2+ 6. Kg1 Qc1+ 7. Qxc1

Comment: Before you post a question please check that the question hasn't been asked before in one form or another. Here are just two previous occurrences of this type of question which have the exact same answers. - https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15761/how-is-this-position-a-draw and https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19719/how-is-this-scenario-a-draw

Comment: @BrianTowers I don't think not checking other questions was the problem here; OP (incorrectly) thought there were three legal moves and thus that stalemate did not apply.

Answer (score 2):

Black is stalemated.  There is no legal move.  The Queen takes out the c file, the Rook takes out the e file, the Pawn blocks d4, and the Queen covers d2.  None of the Black Pawns can move.  The Black Pawns move down the board and are all blocked.